# jquery quicksearch searching also header

Tags: jquery, asp.net, quick-search

I use the modified quicksearch with reset button from this site:

http://michael.theirwinfamily.net/articles/jquery/modify-jquerys-quicksearch-plugin-include-reset-button

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table#MainContent_GV1 tbody tr').quicksearch({
        reset: true,
        resetClass: "resetButton",
        resetLabel: "Reset",
        position: 'before',
        attached: 'table#MainContent_GV1',
        stripeRowClass: ['odd', 'even']
    });
    $(".qs_input").focus();
});
```

It is working but also searching and hiding the header of the `gridview`. Other solutions said to add the `tr` after the `tbody` to search only the rows but not the header. This is not working because the header is also generated as a row (tr):

[image]

how can I exclude the header from the search? Can I set an ID to the header and exclude it somehow with `.not` or another jquery command? Thanks

**Solution:**

Found the solution by adding an element in the first row (header):

`$('<thead></thead>').prependTo('table#MainContent_GV1').append($('table#MainContent_GV1 tr:first'));`

Comment: Chaining a `.not("#id")` to the end of your `$('table#MainContent_GV1 tbody tr')` as you said should work. Have you tested that approach?

Comment: Thanks. Tried `$('table#MainContent_GV1 tbody tr').not("ID").quicksearch({...` and `not("#id")` but still the same problem

Comment: If the following isn't working (example of it working, shown here, albeit without quicksearch) https://jsfiddle.net/e234zLco/ you could try the :not psuedo selector as seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/e234zLco/1/

Just saw your edit. Good job solving the problem.